# Simple Dart test script reports a fail on async request

Tags: dart, testing

I have some code that works but I want to write some test scripts. The tests aren't completing and I'm not sure why.

The Test Script

```
import 'package:members_info/models/digital_card_model.dart';
import 'package:members_info/network/network_digital_card.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  DigitalCardModel testAndrew = DigitalCardModel.fromJson({
"name":"Andrew",
    "phone": "",
    "expired": "Y",
    "lapsing": "Y",
    "externalid": "29033"
  });

  DigitalCardModel testSarah = DigitalCardModel.fromJson({
"name":"Sarah",
    "phone": "",
    "expired": "N",
    "lapsing": "N",
    "externalid": "13"
  });

  group("Test DigitalCardModel request", () {
    test('Andrew', () async {
      DigitalCardModel digitalCard =
          await NetworkDigitalCard().getDigitalCard('andrew@acme.com');

      expect(digitalCard, testAndrew);
    });
    test('Sarah', () async {
      DigitalCardModel digitalCard =
          await NetworkDigitalCard().getDigitalCard('sarah@acme.com');

      expect(digitalCard, testSarah);
    });
  });
}
```

When I run the test in vs code I get this error and it never progresses to the second test:

> Exception has occurred.
> TestFailure (Expected: <Instance of 'DigitalCardModel'>
> Actual: <Instance of 'DigitalCardModel'>
> )

If I mouseover the expect statement I see an empty DigitalCardModel for the result - as if it hasn't waited for the network request to finish.

When I call it in the app it looks like this:

```
late Future<DigitalCardModel> digitalCard =
      NetworkDigitalCard().getDigitalCard(_email);
```

The network call is

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:members_info/extensions/string.dart';
import 'package:members_info/models/digital_card_model.dart';
import 'package:sentry_flutter/sentry_flutter.dart';

class NetworkDigitalCard {
  String getUrl(email) =>
      'https://acme.com/jsonCardDetails?email=$email';

// this gets called by the screen
  Future<DigitalCardModel> getDigitalCard(String email) async {
    if (!email.isValidEmail) {
      return DigitalCardModel(
          
          name: "Invalid Email",
          phone: "",
          expired: "",
          lapsing: "",
          externalid: 0);
    }
    try {
      Response<dynamic> response = await Dio().get(getUrl(email));
      if (response.data['unknown'] == true) {
        return DigitalCardModel(externalid: response.data['externalid']);
      }

      // good data
      return DigitalCardModel.fromJson(response.data);
    } catch (exception, stackTrace) {
      await Sentry.captureException(
        exception,
        stackTrace: stackTrace,
      );
    }
    return DigitalCardModel();
  }

  Future<DigitalCardModel> refreshContent(String email) async {
    return getDigitalCard(email);
  }
}
```

Flutter Dr...

```
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 13.5 22G74 darwin-x64, locale en-AU)
    • Flutter version 3.10.6 on channel stable at /Users/sarah/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f468f3366c (9 weeks ago), 2023-07-12 15:19:05 -0700
    • Engine revision cdbeda788a
    • Dart version 3.0.6
    • DevTools version 2.23.1
```

Comment: "as if it hasn't waited for the network request to finish." If that were true, your test would have timed out.  Your call completed, but it returned an empty object.  My guess would be that your tests neglect to perform some initialization step and that `NetworkDigital().getDigitalCard()` simply can't find an object corresponding to the specified key, returning an empty `DigitalCardModel` on failure.

Comment: Thanks @jamesdlin. I've added the code for the Network call in to the post, it's very simple, no initialisation needed. In vscode the script shows as running with the exception thrown.

Comment: I've changed the order of the tests around and it returns data for my email but there's the added field `hashCode: 334645146` when I jsonEncode it for a developer.log output.

Comment: If there's no initialization, where is the data supposed to come from?

Comment: Thinking that one through I've changed the test to `expect(digitalCard.externalid, testSarah.externalid);` and that seems to work better. it fails on the second test and I need to make the test fail elegrantly.

Comment: The network sets up Dio on the fly and requests a json feed from the webserver.